# Redirect directory pages WITHOUT extension to WITH extension in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

How redirect pages from directory like

site.com/directory/{code} (code with numbers and letters)
to
site.com/directory/{code}.html

I try this code, but its redirect to .html many times like circle

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ directory/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.html)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ directory/$1.html [NS,L,R=301]
```